# Qt Audio and Video stream from Qbuffer

Tags: c++, qt, c++11, audio, video

I'm studying the possibility of create a program in C++/QT to play two flows as stream of bytes.
I'm trying with QtAV component, but every avplayer admits a stream of Qbuffer (io device stream).

My problem is how can I sync the flows?